# Web app with splash screen eventually prevents iOS from exiting the application and prevents restarting

Tags: ios, splash-screen, freeze

I've found myself in an odd situation where I've set up Splash screens in iOS for a web app that I'm building and have found myself not being able to exit it after starting it up/closing/restarting it up a couple of times. This bug seems to also prevent rebooting also, I'm able to recreate this on both an iPad 3 and iPad mini and was wondering if someone else is aware of this?

Essentially in doing so, it's caused:

1. You can't exit the application by tapping the home button, or long pressing it
2. Can't power off the iPad by holding down the off button!
3. The screen won't turn off

I'm using the latest iOS for each and currently seem to be stuck waiting them both to run out of power!

Here's the code I have setup for displaying Splash screens:

```
<link href="images/touch/splash/splash-320x480.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="images/touch/splash/splash-640x960.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="images/touch/splash/splash-640x1136.png"  media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="images/touch/splash/splash-768x1024.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="images/touch/splash/splash-1024x768.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="images/touch/splash/splash-1536x2048.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="images/touch/splash/splash-2048x1636.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

I'm wondering if anybody else is able to recreate to confirm this issue? I wasn't seeing this until I added the Splash screens.

Edit: I was able to reset only by holding the power button and home button.
Edit 2: Now I've rebooted each of them I can't recreate the issue now. I'll keep trying but there doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to what caused it on 2 separate devices.

Comment: After doing some testing I've found it occurs when you try to exit while the splash screen is still active, after doing that a couple of times it results in not being able to exit at all..

Comment: I've encountered this as well. It seems like a fairly substantial bug.

Comment: Seems to be the same problem reported in [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16225693/795339).